# Perplexities in spring security method POST and GET

Tags: spring, security, post, spring-security, get

I have a strong doubt in the use of Spring security specifically I want to know how to defend functions connected to the controller (GET and POST). Let me explain better, to defend I do not intend to perform that action to authorized users with certain roles, I intend to defend that action even by authorized users. Specific example: the user knowing the identifier of an object calls a POST form directly from the url, not passing through any button / link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are asking:

*How do I prevent POST requests from other sources?*

And you are stating that:

*I want to ensure that the POST request only comes from my form!*

Spring Security does this automatically for HTML FORMs. We call this feature

**CSRF Prevention**

- **C**ross
- **S**ite
- **R**equest
- **F**orgery

Spring Security does this automatically for you. Any POST request is validated to ensure it has a *CSRF token*. A value that Spring sets when the browser loads the form. Without this token, Spring Security [returns a 403 error (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676831/getting-http-403-error-in-a-post-method-with-httpbasic-auth-using-spring-securit)

For example:

```java
        http
            //application security
            .mvcMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
        ;
```

has CSRF protection enabled. To disable it, we add `.csrf().disable()`

```java
        http
            //application security
            .mvcMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
        ;
```

You can see how [this user (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676831/getting-http-403-error-in-a-post-method-with-httpbasic-auth-using-spring-securit) was unable to submit a POST without a CSRF token. That user's solution was to disable CSRF protection, because it is enabled by default.

The answer to your question is: *You don't have to do anything. CSRF protection is enabled by default.*

Answer (score 0):

it's already done by default.
Perplexities solved